# C++/fstream: cannot create a new file

Tags: c++, file, fstream

For some reason, the following code cannot create a new file, i.e. if the file already exists it overwrites it, otherwise it does nothing at all:

```
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::fstream fs("test_out.log"); // <-- does not create a new file!
    //std::fstream fs("test_out.log", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out); // <-- does not create a new file!

    fs << "TEST" << std::endl;
}
```

What have I done wrong?

C++ compiler: clang
System: OS-X 10.9.5

Comment: at the end you should write  fs.close()

Comment: @Android400: A manual close makes no sense. After the `fs` object is destroyed while leaving the scope of main the file is closed while fs is destructed.

Comment: yes in this example make a manual close no sense but in other usage it's not useless.

Comment: @Android400 In other circumstances other code makes sense to achieve other things, right. But what will this help us here?

Comment: @Android400 It's very rare to encounter such a situation, unless you've got the bad habit of reusing variables for different purposes.

Comment: @Android400 If a process ends, nothing will created from that process. Can you explain a real situation where your comment is substantial?

Comment: @Android400 C++ is not Java. The destructor for `fstream` closes the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a new file to write:

```
std::ofstream fs("test_out.log");
```

do the job.

If you use `std::ios_base::in` the file MUST exist

Comment: why `std::fstream fs("test_out.log", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out);` failed to create the file?

Comment: @GilsonPJ: If you use `std::ios_base::in` the file MUST exist.

Comment: Thanks. without `in` it is creating the file

Comment: Does it mean that if I want to open a file in (ios_base::in | ios_base::out) mode, I had better do: { ofstream fs("test_out.log", ios_base::app); } first, to guarantee the file exists?